# How to pass an uploaded image back to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, processing

The setup I work on is the following: A HTML-page with a canvas element displaying a [Processing JS sketch](http://processingjs.org/) and a form that allows to pass parameters to the sketch using JS-function `Processing.getInstanceById(getProcessingSketchId()).setSomeParam();`, which works just fine.

The user should also be able to upload an image to the server, the name/path of which is then also handed to the sketch to do `loadImage(String path)`. The file upload (using PHP from [here](http://www.codeforest.net/upload-crop-and-resize-images-with-php)) works perfectly fine as well but now here is the question:

How can I get the name of the uploaded image on the server and pass it to the Processing sketch?

If the form's *action* tag points to a distinct PHP-file, the site with the canvas sketch is quit (variable `$destination` not available) **or** if the form's *action* tag points to the site itself (being a PHP-site, checking for `if(isset($_POST['formSubmitted'])) {`), the sketch is restarted losing all the previously changed parameters.

I also managed to have the form submission target to an internal iframe and display the uploaded image there, but that still doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks a lot in advance for any helpful hints!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the data flow worked out but are struggling because a standard form upload causes a page refresh.

I would suggest using AJAX to post the image to a specific PHP image receiver service.  When the AJAX upload is complete, the javascript can then call to the server to fetch the uploaded object and manipulate it as needed without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thank you, PaulProgrammer, for your quick reply. I followed the path proposing AJAX. When crawling for tutorials, I stumbled upon [this](http://www.ajaxf1.com/product/ajax-file-upload.html). In fact, it is not using AJAX at all but nevertheless offers a solution to my initial problem. The form's action php targets to an `iframe`. At the end of the php, the Javascript `window.top.window.tryLoading("<?php echo $destination; ?>");` returns the upload path back to the parent html with the form.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works for you. For folks who might stumble on this answer in the future, I would caution against iframe, mostly because of my own experiences and fluctuations in how iframes and security constraints are handled by browsers over time.